# How to check if entry contains word and print random entry from table PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Based on a user's profile, I'm looking to see if a column from their profile contains certain terms, and if they do, select one random entry from a specific table.

Also, in the end, I want to only print one of the entries. So if their profile contains all 5 words, I want it the PHP to still only print one random entry each time the page is refreshed.

Could someone please point me in the right direction? The code I have at the minute is as follows;

```
<?php

   session_start();
   include 'includes/Connect.php';
   $username=$_SESSION['myusername'];

   $query = "SELECT `CC` FROM  `$username`";              
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $pos1 = strpos($result,'Honesty');
   $pos2 = strpos($result,'Loyalty');
   $pos3 = strpos($result,'Trust');
   $pos4 = strpos($result,'Empathy');
   $pos5 = strpos($result,'Respect');

   while($Aff = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $data = array();

   if($pos1!==false){
       $query1 = "SELECT Affirmation FROM `Aff CC1` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
       for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query1); $x++) 
       {
       $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1);
       }
   }
   if($pos2!==false){
       $query2 = "SELECT Affirmation FROM `Aff CC2` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
       for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query2); $x++) 
       {
       $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2);
       }
   }
   if($pos3!==false){
       $query3 = "SELECT Affirmation FROM `Aff CC3` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
       for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query3); $x++) 
       {
       $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3);
       }
   }
   if($pos4!==false){
       $query4 = "SELECT Affirmation FROM `Aff CC4` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
       for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query4); $x++) 
       {
       $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query4);
       }
   }
   if($pos5!==false){
       $query5 = "SELECT Affirmation FROM `Aff CC5` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
       for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query5); $x++) 
       {
       $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query5);
       }
   }   
  }
 ?>
```

---

So I've done this instead and I'm still getting nothing.

```
session_start();
                                include 'includes/Connect.php';
                                $username=$_SESSION['myusername'];

                                $query = "SELECT `CC` FROM `Profile` where `Username`=`$username`";              
                                $result = mysql_query($query);
                                $pos1 = strpos($result,'Honesty');
                                $pos2 = strpos($result,'Loyalty');
                                $pos3 = strpos($result,'Trust');
                                $pos4 = strpos($result,'Empathy');
                                $pos5 = strpos($result,'Respect');
                                $data = array();

                                for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($result); $x++) {

                                    if($pos1!==false){
                                        $CCID=1;
                                    }

                                    if($pos2!==false){
                                        $CCID=2;
                                    }

                                    if($pos3!==false){
                                        $CCID=3;
                                    }

                                    if($pos4!==false){
                                        $CCID=4;
                                    }

                                    if($pos5!==false){
                                        $CCID=5;
                                    }

                                    $querymain = "SELECT `Affirmation` FROM `Affs` WHERE CCID=$CCID ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
                                    $resultmain = mysql_query($querymain);

                                    for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($resultmain); $x++) 
                                    {
                                    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultmain);
                                    }
                                }

                                echo json_encode($data);
                                mysql_close($conn);

                                ?>
```

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's deprecated, dangerous if you're not careful to [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/php) every value you put in your query, and is being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) outlines the recommended best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you've got an array with up to X amount of items.  You can just pick a random item out of the array, similar to how you're picking a random item from the db.

Basically, just do a count on your `$data` array to see how many items you have in there.  Then pick a random number between 0 and however many items there are, minus 1.  You can now access that specific item from within the array.

Try something like this after you have your `$data` array built:

```
<?php

$line_count = count($data) - 1;

print "RANDOM LINE: ".$data[get_random_line($line_count)];


function get_random_line($line_count) {
    mt_srand(microtime() * 1000000);
    $random_number = rand(0, $line_count);
    return $random_number;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Quixrick. Have you any idea where I'm going wrong with the code I already have though as nothing's showing in my array yet to run your suggested code on? Thanks again

Comment: I'd be more than happy to help.  First, can you explain to me what you're doing?  I'll take a stab at it and you can correct me.  Looks like you have a table for every username.  So if I put in my username as `Quixrick`, then you're getting the `CC` field out of table `Quixrick`.  Then, for some reason, you're checking to see if it contains the words 'Honesty', 'Loyalty', etc.  Now the thing is, you are looping through `$result` later and storing it in `$Aff`.  That's probably where you should be checking to see if the words match.  Check it on `$Aff` instead of `$result` inside the loop. ...

Comment: Okay, so now, you've got 5 similar tables `Aff CC1`, `Aff CC2`, etc.  Probably you should just have one table and then just have some sort of `ID` field to mark 1, 2, 3, etc.  [Also, as a side note, it's not really good practice to have your table names contain spaces.]  Alrighty, I doubt this is the case, but let's just say that `$pos1` has something in it and makes it to the `if` condition.  There, you are defining your query (`$query1 = ...`), but you are not actually executing it.  You should be executing the query and then using `mysql_num_rows` on `$result1`, `$result2`, etc.

Comment: Finally, you should probably be picking out `Affirmation` from your query instead of assigning the whole `mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)` to `$data`.  Something like this: `$row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1); $affirmation1 = $row1['Affirmation']; $data[] = $affirmation1;`  Hopefully that will get you off to a good start.  Let me know if you still can't get things to work and I'll try and help troubleshoot further.

Comment: You're an absolute gent Quixrick. You'd be surprised how hard it is to get someone to just help round here. Majority of times you just get smart comments about how people would scrap your code altogether and go a different direction. So if I attach an id for each of my CC to one "affirmation" table, then you think it would be cleaner?